# How to create a funciton in cypress that looks for "not contains" words?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I want to test the search filter in screen. When I enter the word in the search bar, I want to see that it words that only contains entered. I can not find a function that provide in Cypress

Comment: Please, provide some minimal reproducible code. As far as I understand you need to type some text in search bar and then check that result list contains only those words that you typed. Yo need to access to the list like this `cy.get('.list-item').invoke('text').should('contain', 'some word');`

Answer (score 13):

You could easily use the not.contain option. Syntax would be like this:

```js
cy.get('element').should('not.contain', 'value_it_should_not_contain')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cy.get('[class^=Input_error]').should('not.have.text', 'Insufficient');
```